# Savefig to PNG but half a the picture appears

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am saving a table as PNG but when I open it, half of it appears:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 2)) # set size frame
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the x axis
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False) 
ax.set_frame_on(False) 

tabla = table(ax, data, loc='upper right', colWidths=[0.17]*len(data.columns))  # where df is your data frame
tabla.auto_set_font_size(False) # Activate set fontsize manually
tabla.set_fontsize(5) # if ++fontsize is necessary ++colWidths
tabla.scale(1, 1) 
plt.savefig('/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/market-team/table.png', transparent=True, format='png',
           bbox_inches=None, pad_inches=0.1, dpi=100)
```

when I do `plt.show()` it shows the below dataframe:
[image]

But when I open it with an Editor, I only have half of the image:
[image]

any idea why? thanks!

Comment: Why is the figsize set to (12,2)?

Comment: Sometimes you have to wait a little bit before the whole PNG file is compiled. Even when you see the file icon generated, it could still be in the process of writing it and when you click on it that can stop the process.

Comment: @r-beginners it does not change the output, even when I remove it, ther is no change

Comment: You commented on whether the screen display size and the saved save size are different, but that doesn't affect it. I have no proof, but is the font size the same for 10 or 12 as it normally is?

Comment: It does affect it. If I can change the screen display size, then my saved save file is smaller if I decrease, but I do not have the half of my image. I do not have the bottom of my image.

Comment: @Viktor.w have you tried to set `bbox_inches='tight'`?

Comment: @CarloZanocco, indeed, it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving the figure with `bbox_inches=None` option:

```
plt.savefig('/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/market-team/table.png', transparent=True, format='png',
           bbox_inches=None, pad_inches=0.1, dpi=100)
```

Replace it with: `bbox_inches='tight'`.

The option `bbox_inches` Bound box in inches: only the given portion of the figure is saved. If 'tight', try to figure out the tight bbox of the figure. Set it as “tight” for proper fit of the saved figure.